# Site or example project / downloadable programme resource anywhere for the EV3 mindstorm?

Tags: ev3, programming

There seems to be lots of available examples for the NXC version, but I can't find anything for the EV3. I thought that there would be a load of example project files with the software but there's just physical build instructions, and I can't find anything on the site either.

Can anyone point me in the right direction for downloadable EV3 project files?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found a few project collections, but they tend to be hit-and-miss regarding the number and quality of downloadables.

- [Into Robotics](http://www.intorobotics.com/best-lego-mindstorms-ev3-robotics-projects/)
- [Mindcub3r, a single project](http://mindcuber.com/mindcub3r/mindcub3r.html)
- [EV3 projects on leJOS forums](http://www.lejos.org/forum/viewforum.php?f=19)
- [Mindstorms project collection on Genius, contains projects for NXT too that could be adapted for EV3](http://genius.com/2511947)
- [Tilted Twister, a collection of NXT projects that could be adapted to EV3](http://www.tiltedtwister.com/index.html)

Do these fit your needs or would you like something different?

Comment: thanks for the links, I've taken a few ideas... The best tutorial that I've found by a mile (the official ones are awful IMO) is this one : http://www.stemhq.org/custom-blocks  Not strictly related to the post I guess but it's been helpful for me so maybe others can use it....I wish that I could use the Java functionality and such but it'd throw everything out of reach for the rest of the group, I'm having to do all the work as it is :/